# How to get coumn names without getting truncated in SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, sqlplus

How to do I get column names without getting truncated in SQLPLUS in Unix for select statement. This might look like duplicate question, but I have been searching for hours but couldn't find a convenient solution.

So far what I have found is

```
COLUMN COLUMN_NAME FORMAT SIZE;
```

Or

```
SELECT COLUMN1|| ',' || COLUMN2 || ',' || COLUMN3 FROM TABLE;
```

Both involves hardcoding,Is there any simpler solution without hardcoding.

Sorry for making it hard

```
Query: select * from Employee;
```

It has column names as Name,Salary,Age

What I get is:

```
 Name   Sala  Ag
 Steve  1000  30
 John   2000  25
```

What I want is:

```
 Name  Salary Age
 Steve 1000   30
 John  2000   25
```

Comment: err what exactly is getting truncated?  can you give us an example of expected output?

Comment: Column names getting truncated based on column data, For ex Location as L

Comment: Where are the column names being truncated -- this makes no sense... SQL code does not have a UI -- where are the column names being displayed?  What system are you using to make the query, what is the content of the query.  There is no way to answer unless you answer these things.

Comment: Oops, Sorry I'm using Unix.

Comment: I don't wanna use desc tablename,I'm looking for a way that select statement should return column header along with the data without truncating column names.

Comment: your question makes no sense because it does not do this.  Please show the query you are using, the output you are getting and the EXPECTED output you want to see.

Comment: I had updated the question, hope you understand :-)

Answer (score 3):

Setting size (width) of a column in SQL*Plus output.

```
SQL> column sex format a5
```

Seeing the current settings in effect.

```
SQL> column
```

Getting further help on usage.

```
SQL> help column
```

**UPDATE**

Setting format for all columns (in an awkward way). Assuming my `users` table defined as follows.

```
create table users(
  id number
, username varchar2(20)
, credentials varchar2(90)
, lastname varchar2(20) not null
, firstname varchar2(20)
, emailaddress varchar2(42)
, emailisvalid number(1)
, sex char(1)
, created date default sysdate
);
```

We could issue this command putting the output into the file `login.sql` which is automatically executed every time you start SQL*Plus.

```
SQL> spool login.sql

SQL> select 'column ' || column_name || ' format a' || length(column_name) || ';'
from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'USERS';

column ID format a2;
column USERNAME format a8;
column PASSWORD format a8;
column LASTNAME format a8;
column FIRSTNAME format a9;
column EMAILADDRESS format a12;
column EMAILISVALID format a12;
column SEX format a3;
column CREATED format a7;
```

Comment: Is there any way I can format all columns of a select statement at once without specifying individual column name. Something Like "column * format a5;"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the way to set format for all columns at once. It's seems the `COLUMN FORMAT` is used to set format for individual columns. Though if your table structure doesn't change often, you could use the (rather awkward) approach I included in the update.

Comment: Thank you so much, doesn't help me though.

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful, but you could also try [`MARKUP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169539) option to generate HTML output and then use browser or other tools to read/analyze the output: `SQL> set mark html on`

Answer (score -1):

This problem:

```
Name   Sala  Ag
Steve  1000  30
John   2000  25
```

Can be solved like this:

```
SELECT Name,
       CAST(Salary) AS VARCHAR(6) AS Salary,
       CAST(Age) AS VARCHAR(3) AS Age
FROM Employee;
```

Note, once again... this is not what the query is returning, but how the client is displaying the results.  Use a different client it would work differently.  In this case the client is formatting the columns based on the column data type.  When it sees a varchar (like name) it goes to the max data size.  So we give it a bigger string data it will look ok.

This is NOT part of what is happening on the Server -- this goes to how the client displays.  So if the query is going to be used by a different client (eg web page or application call) this won't matter when it is actually used by those clients.

Comment: Read my question completely ,I don't want to hardcode, consider if I have to spool 100 different tables, I cant hardcode every single column name, I agree it's about the client, but there should be way. Thanks for trying out.